# Problems with getting number of swaps and passing through in simple bubble sort

Tags: python, sorting, counter, bubble-sort

While solving prog. task with bubble-sort I ran into a problem. So, i need to count the number of swaps in array and the number of passing through array. Actually, there is output.
In my code array is being sorted properly but counters are working wrong.

```
step = int(input())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
passage_number = 0
swap_number = 0
for x in range(step):
    for i in range(step-x-1):
        passage_number += 1
        if a[i] <= a[i+1]:
            a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i]
            swap_number += 1

print(passage_number, swap_number)
```

Sample input (two strings), and output:

8
3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6

5 8

(now it returns smth like "21 14" etc, depends on position of variables)

I think that the problem is in incorrect variables position but I can't solve this easy problem for about 6 hours. I tried to set variables ib different positions and to expirement with variable 'step' but all attempts was unsuccessful.
I'll be very grateful if you'll show me what should I change in my code to solve this problem (suddenly google has not answer btw :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the task is using the so-called 'modified bubble sort' which utilizes a flag that halts the algorithm if a single pass through it results in no swaps.  To implement this you just need to set a flag before the loops begin, have the outer lap reset it, and have any swap flip it, then have a conditional-break statement to test after every passage. The loop section of your code would be something like this:

```
for x in range(step - 1):
    passage_number += 1
    flag = True
    for i in range(step - 1):
        if a[i] > a[i+1]:
            a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i]
            swap_number += 1
            flag = False
    if flag:
        break
```

That gives `5 8` for your sequence.

Answer (score 0):

1. are you sorting in ascending order? if yes, the swap condition should be `if a[i]  > a[i+1]:`, not `if a[i] <= a[i+1]:`
2. `passage_number += 1` needs to be put between `for x in range(step):` and `for i in range(step-x-1):`

Comment: 1) yes, i was just expirementing and forgot to change it, 2) thanks but damn counters are not working correct, on sample input (in question) it returns "8 13". if i will print array after every swap, there is strange things in terminal: [link](https://prnt.sc/rrbaww). why it prints array when it is already sorted? very very strange

Comment: @Dismay000 why shouldn't it print the sorted array? you need to break the outer loop if there was no swap on the last pass, otherwise it will naturally do all "step" passes

Comment: @Dismay000 And show the full code you use (including the part where you print the array). The one in your question (including those 2 edits suggested by me) gives "8 8" - there are only 8 swaps, I wonder where that 13 came from

Comment: [here is the last code ver](https://pastebin.com/u4KLsazM)
now it gives "8 8", i think that obviously the task is incorrect. but anyway thanks

Comment: @Dismay000 The task is rather sneakily using the 'modified bubble sort' see answer